# Integrating hypercohomology classes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, derham-cohomology

Let $X$ be a complex variety. By Poincare's lemma, its singular cohomology can be computed as hypercohomology of the holomorphic de Rham complex (viewing $X$ as a complex manifold)
$$\text{H}^\cdot(X,\mathbf{C})\ \simeq\ \text{H}^\cdot(X,\Omega^\bullet).$$
By GAGA the right side is the same as the hypercohomology of the complex of *algebraic* de Rham complex.

In any case, you can compute the hypercohomology $ \text{H}^\cdot(X,\Omega^\bullet)$ using Cech cohomology, in terms of an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $X$. For instance, if $X$ has dimension $n$, a representative of $\text{H}^n(X,\Omega^\bullet)$ is a collection of $n$ forms
$$\omega_{n,\alpha}\ \in\ \text{H}^0(U_\alpha,\Omega^n)$$
which do not quite glue to a global $n$-form, but there are $n-1$ forms
$$\omega_{n-1,\alpha,\beta}\ \in\ \text{H}^0(U_\alpha\cap U_\beta,\Omega^{n-1})$$
such that $d\omega_{n-1,\alpha,\beta}=\omega_\alpha-\omega_\beta$ on the intersection. Similarly, there are $n-2$ forms $\omega_{n-2,\alpha,\beta,\gamma}$ such that $d\omega_{n-2,\alpha,\beta,\gamma}=\omega_{n-1,\alpha,\beta}-\omega_{n-1,\alpha,\gamma}+\omega_{n-1,\beta,\gamma}$, and so on.

For example, on $X=\mathbf{P}^1$ with its standard cover by two affine lines, $\text{H}^2(\mathbf{P}^1)$ is generated by the meromorphic differential form
$$dx/x\ \in\ \text{H}^0(\mathbf{A}^1_0\cap\mathbf{A}^1_\infty, \Omega^1). $$

---

**Question:** Assume that $X$ is smooth and proper. We then know that an element of $\text{H}^\cdot(X,\mathbf{C}) \simeq \text{H}^\cdot(X,\Omega^\bullet)$ can be integrated. What does integration look like in terms of these hypercohomology classes?

---

Looking at the $\mathbf{P}^1$ example, one might guess that the answer has something interesting to do with residues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to see this is algebraically. Let $\omega_X = \Omega^n_X$. The map you seek to describe is
$$
\int_X \colon \mathrm{H}^n(X,\omega_X) \to \mathbb{C}
$$
Abstractly, it arises as the counit of the Serre duality adjunction
$$
\mathrm{H}^n(X,-) \dashv -\otimes \omega_X
$$
By the compatibility between local and global duality, there is a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\otimes_P \mathrm{H}^n_P(\omega_X)@>can>> \mathrm{H}^n(X,\omega_X)\\
@V \otimes_P \mathrm{res}_P V V  @VV\int_XV\\
\mathbb{C} @= \mathbb{C}
\end{CD}
and the maps $\mathrm{res}_P$ that arise by local duality, are computed through higher dimensional residues. This is explained with great detail in J. Lipman's blue book:

*Dualizing sheaves, differentials and residues on algebraic varieties*. Astérisque, No. **117** (1984).

For the comparison between the algebraic and the analytic case and the $\frac{1}{(2 \pi i)^n}$ factor (up to a sign), see

Sastry & Tong, The Grothendieck Trace and the de Rham Integral, *Canad. Math. Bull.* Vol. **46** (3), 2003 pp. 429–440.

To make things more explicit, you may assume that your covering $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ is finite and each $U_i$ is the complement of a certain section $f_i$ of a line bundle. In this case a Czech cocycle is defined by a residual symbol
$$
\left[  \frac{ w } { f_0 \dots f_n }  \right]
$$
with $w$ a meromorphic $n$-form. This is described on page 195 of

Hartshorne, *Residues and duality*. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, **20**, Springer-Verlag, 1966.

So the objective is to compute
$$
\int_X \left[  \frac{ w } { f_0 \dots f_n }  \right]
$$

The Czech-cocycle/symbol induces a certain element

$$
\left[  \frac{ w } { f_0 \dots \hat{f_i} \dots f_n }  \right]_P
$$
in $\mathrm{H}^n_P(\omega_X)$ where $p\in U_i$ so $(f_i)_P$ is invertible in $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$. This element is describable using a Koszul complex to compute $\mathrm{H}^n_P(\omega_X)$. Finally the computation of the integral is reduced to compute
$$
\mathrm{res}_P \left[  \frac{ w } { f_0 \dots \hat{f_i} \dots f_n }  \right]_P
$$.
This can be done explicitly, over the points $P$ that are *poles* of the differential form $w$. Locally at $P$
$$
w = \phi f_0 \wedge \hat{f_i} \wedge f_n 
$$
with $\phi$ in the fraction field of $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$. Then,
$$
\mathrm{res}_P \left[  \frac{ w } { f_0 \dots \hat{f_i} \dots f_n }  \right]_P = a_{(-1, \dots, -1)}
$$
where $a_{(-1, \dots, -1)} \in \mathbb{C}$ denotes the corresponding coefficient in the Laurent expansion of $\phi$. This is described  using the identification of $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,P}$ with the power series ring $\mathbb{C}[[f_0 \dots \hat{f_i} \dots f_n]]$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understand - does this answer tell you explicitly how to integrate a Cech cocyle?

Comment: Notice that  you may represent $\mathrm{H}^n(X, \omega_X)$ as a certain quotient of $\check{C}^n(X,\omega_X)$   i.e. of $\prod_\alpha\Gamma(U_\alpha,\omega_X)$, and analogously for $H^n_P(\omega_X)$.Then, you use the diagram I mention. It is not immediate to unravel all definitions but it can be done in a relatively explicit way under the smoothness hypothesis.

Comment: @Meow, I hope the edit makes all of this more explicit.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Just one last question - how are you going from a collection $(\omega_{n,\alpha})\in \text{H}^0(U_\alpha,\Omega^n)$ to your meromorphic form $w$? Is the meromorphic form just equal to $\omega_{n,\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$, then you prove that changing $\alpha$ does not affect the integral?

Comment: @Meow You may regard your holomorphic form along $U_\alpha$, $\omega_{n,\alpha}$, as a meromorphic form along all $X$. But the cocycle condition says that $\omega_{n,\alpha}|_{U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}} = \omega_{n,\beta}|_{U_{\alpha} \cap U_{\beta}}$ so all these meromorphic forms agree. That's what I call $w$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is correct. We have $\omega_{n,\alpha}\vert_{U_\alpha\cap U_\beta}=\omega_{n,\beta}\vert_{U_\alpha\cap U_\beta}+d\omega_{n-1,\alpha,\beta}\vert_{U_\alpha\cap U_\beta}$, where here a Cech representative of a hypercohomology class of $\Omega^\bullet$ has the form $\{(\omega_{k,\alpha_1,...,\alpha_k}): k=0,...,n, \alpha_1,...,\alpha_k\in I\}$ where $I$ is the index set of the cover.

Comment: Ok, you are right, but the difference is a closed form whose integral vanishes.

Comment: Aha, that answers my question! Thanks so much for your time again.